# Looking for a more pythonic way of converting list of lists to string

Tags: python-3.x

I have python (3.7) code that works, but it's ugly, and I'm sure there's a more elegant way of doing what I want to do.  I have 9 3x3 grids that I want to print out (plus some line separators) for a tic-tac-toe game.

I basically want the output to look like this (sample of the first row)

```
█ █│   │███
 █ │ 2 │█ █
█ █│   │███
```

The code below does this, but it seems like there's a better way, and I'm not sure how to do this in an elegant for loop.

Thanks in advance!

```
choice_x = [
    ['█', ' ', '█'],
    [' ', '█', ' '],
    ['█', ' ', '█']
]

choice_o = [
    ['█', '█', '█'],
    ['█', ' ', '█'],
    ['█', '█', '█']
]

v_grid = [
    ['│'],
    ['│'],
    ['│']
]

empty_grid = [
    [' ',' ',' '],
    [' ','2',' '],
    [' ',' ',' ']
]

row1 = [
    choice_x, v_grid, empty_grid, v_grid, choice_o
]

#for n in range(0,4):
slice1 = [sublist[0][:3] for sublist in row1]
result = ''.join([''.join(item) for item in slice1])
print(result)

slice2 = [sublist[1][:3] for sublist in row1]
result = ''.join([''.join(item) for item in slice2])
print(result)

slice3 = [sublist[2][:3] for sublist in row1]
result = ''.join([''.join(item) for item in slice3])
print(result)
#end for loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using list of lists, but knowing the size of the board:

```
GRID_SIZE = 3
SEP = '|'
choice_x = ['█', ' ', '█',
            ' ', '█', ' ',
            '█', ' ', '█']
empty_grid = [' ', ' ', ' ',
              ' ', '2', ' ',
              ' ', ' ', ' ']
choice_o = ['█', '█', '█',
            '█', ' ', '█',
            '█', '█', '█']

for i in range(0, GRID_SIZE**2, GRID_SIZE):
    s1 = ''.join(choice_x[i:i+GRID_SIZE])
    s2 = ''.join(empty_grid[i:i+GRID_SIZE])
    s3 = ''.join(choice_o[i:i+GRID_SIZE])
    print(SEP.join([s1, s2, s3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Printer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.grid = [[[[" " for y in range(3)] for x in range(3)] for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]

    def render(self):
        print("-" * 13)
        for y in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                print("|",end="")
                for x in range(3):
                    print("".join(self.grid[y][x][j]), end="|")
                print()
            print("-" * 13)

    def set_char(self, x, y, char):
        self.grid[y][x] = char

choice_x = [
    ['█', ' ', '█'],
    [' ', '█', ' '],
    ['█', ' ', '█']
]

choice_o = [
    ['█', '█', '█'],
    ['█', ' ', '█'],
    ['█', '█', '█']
]

empty_grid = [
    [' ',' ',' '],
    [' ','2',' '],
    [' ',' ',' ']
]

board = Printer()
board.set_char(0,1,choice_x)
board.set_char(1,1,empty_grid)
board.set_char(2,1,choice_o)
board.render()

print("\n" * 2)

board.set_char(2, 0, choice_o)
board.render()
```

Output:

```
-------------
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |
-------------
|█ █|   |███|
| █ | 2 |█ █|
|█ █|   |███|
-------------
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |
-------------



-------------
|   |   |███|
|   |   |█ █|
|   |   |███|
-------------
|█ █|   |███|
| █ | 2 |█ █|
|█ █|   |███|
-------------
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |
-------------
```

---

Board x/y explaination:

```
   0 1 2
  -------
0 | | | |
  -------
1 | | | |
  -------
2 | | | |
  -------
```

As you can see, both start at 0, and top-left.

---

Hope this helps :)